# Como puedo obtener una diferencia de 2 columnas

Tags: dataframe, lambda

Tengo un dataframe historial
que tiene la siguientes estructura:
ticket(int), time(string), price(float), comment(string)

```
        ticket                time    price      comment
0    934610033 2023-08-14 00:34:30  1.27086  CT934609466
1    934610034 2023-08-14 00:35:02  1.27022  CT934610033
2    934492762 2023-08-14 00:26:03  1.27151  CT934492760
3    934609782 2023-08-14 00:26:33  1.26551  CT934492762
4    934610019 2023-08-14 00:34:14  1.26989             
..         ...                 ...      ...          ...
245  936127767 2023-08-18 05:39:06  1.27549             
246  936127496 2023-08-18 05:36:06  1.27534             
247  936128805 2023-08-18 05:46:42  1.27583             
248  936370047 2023-08-18 21:51:10  1.27441             
249  936320348 2023-08-18 18:18:00  1.27359             
[250 rows x 4 columns]
```

Las filas varían, pueden ser más o menos, pero lo que necesitaría hacer es lo siguiente:
La columna de **ticket** tiene asociada una ó mas columnas **comment**, la columna comment puede estar vacía como se ve en las últimas, la idea es hallar el absoluto de la diferencia entre el precio del **ticket** y su columna **comment** asociada, multiplicada por 100,000 cuya diferencia sea mayor o igual a 400 y ponerla en una última columna.

Por ejemplo la **1** (comment=CT934610033) y la **0** (ticket=934610033) fila la diferencia es -64, el absoluto es 64, esa fila no se filtraría, la diferencia entre la **3** y la **2** da **600**, esa si se filtraria.

suponiendo que fuera la única que cumpliera esa condición el dataframe resultante debería quedar con sus pares ó más así:

```
        ticket                time    price      comment  diferencia
2    934492762 2023-08-14 00:26:03  1.27151  CT934492760     
3    934609782 2023-08-14 00:26:33  1.26551  CT934492762      600
```

Intenté ésto:

```
historial[historial.ticket.to_string in historial.comment]

historial.loc[historial['ticket'].isin(historial['comment'][:2])]
```

Estaba viendo si con una función lambda, pero apenas lo voy a estudiar.

Pero no funcionó, de antemano gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).